# aws sagemaker python sdk : Predict function giving weird errors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a tf model (not using any sagemaker service). I used tf 2.1.0 version. 
I saved it with the following signature def 
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDef:

```
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 80)
        name: text_input_1:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['predictions'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 738)
        name: output_1/Identity:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I zipped the model and created a Model object using [AWS sagemaker's Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model.html#sagemaker.model.Model.deploy)

```
model = Model(model_data=s3_location,
              role=role,
              framework_version='2.1.0')
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge') {code}
```

**After the Model is created, I have a lot of trouble predicting.** I get weird errors such as 
`"error": "Session was not created with a graph before Run()!"` or
`"error": "Failed to process element: 0 of 'instances' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON Value:`

I tried both predictor.predict() method as well as client.invoke_endpoint() methods using various formats such as predictor.predict(list), various variations of tf serving REST API formats using `"instances"` format. I tried json.dumps() on all variations as well. But nothing works. 
Can someone suggest a way to predict. As shown in the signature_def my input is of shape (1,80).
Thank you

I'm looking for an answer of the form `predictor.predict($what here?)`. Or suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It'd be helpful if you can share what you are passing to `predictor.predict()`.

The input should be the list that is the value of "instances", e.g. if with the TFS REST API you wanted to send:

```
{
  "instances": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
}
```

then your code should look like:

```py
predictor.predict([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

Here's an example notebook that demonstrates this: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_serving_container/tensorflow_serving_container.ipynb